# Elasticsearch for multiple language support

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 5.1.1.
I have a requirement where in I want to index data in multiple languages.

I used following mapping:

PUT http://localhost:9200/movies

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "title": {
      "properties": {
        "title": { 
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "de": { 
              "type":     "string",
              "analyzer": "german"
            },
            "en": { 
              "type":     "string",
              "analyzer": "english"
            },
            "fr": { 
              "type":     "string",
              "analyzer": "french"
            },
            "es": { 
              "type":     "string",
              "analyzer": "spanish"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when I try to insert some data as :

POST  http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1

```
{
"title.en" :"abc123"
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason": "[IQ7CUTp][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/index[p]]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "[title] is defined as an object in mapping [movie] but this name is already used for a field in other types"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Can someone point me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `title` field is declared as a `string` and you're trying to access the `title.en` sub-field like you would do if `title` was and `object` field. You need to change your mapping like this instead and then it will work:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "title": {
      "properties": {
        "title": { 
          "type": "object",           <--- change this
          "properties": {             <--- and this
            "de": { 
              "type":     "string",
              "analyzer": "german"
            },
            "en": { 
              "type":     "string",
              "analyzer": "english"
            },
            "fr": { 
              "type":     "string",
              "analyzer": "french"
            },
            "es": { 
              "type":     "string",
              "analyzer": "spanish"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Val and @christinabo,both of your solutions worked.
Basically I wanted to use "movie" as type. Now I can post data.
 
 
Now I want to test if my analyzers are really working for different languages, how can I do that.
Right now it is accepting whtever I am posting and returning in search.

Comment: Setting the `english` analyzer on a field won't prevent you from indexing spanish content into it, so ES will accept any string you post in all your language-specific fields. The best way to test is to hit the [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) and see how your text is analyzed.

Comment: there's nothing wrong in analyzing `summer` with the `spanish` analyzer. ES will not translate your content.

Comment: ok Thanks,
Looks like I need to read in more depth about analyzers :)
But can you please brief me the advantage of using "spanish" analyzer or language specific analyzers since we can achieve same thing using "english" analyzer ?
Apologies if question is very basic.

Comment: Each [language analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html) applies different rules (stemming, stop words, etc) that are specific to each language. You should definitely read up on that.

Comment: ,I have posted another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300200/elasticsearch-can-we-apply-both-n-gram-and-language-analyzers-during-indexing , can you please help ?

Comment: What about this question? Anything missing?

Comment: Nope nothing missing , these analyzers are working fine, Now I have to combine these analyzers with n-gram analyzer hence created new thread.

Comment: can I get help on other question please ? I have posted it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300200/elasticsearch-can-we-apply-both-n-gram-and-language-analyzers-during-indexing

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you have defined the `title` both as a `type` and as a `property`.
The error seems to state this issue.

From your post call, I see that the `type` is the *movie*.
Do you really want the *title* as a type?
You should define the mapping for the title inside the movie type.