# How should I configure elasticsearch mapping in order to get the MySQL "like" like behaviour?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field say "name" which can contain :

1. Multiple words;
2. both lower case and upper case;
3. digits;
4. special characters: !@#$%^&*();
5. different languages like: english, french, danish and others.

The task is to define the settings of this field so that when I search I can get the desirable results as follows: no matter what I pass in as searched string(ex: '1', 'a', '#1' 'èæ qтчert1') I should get all documents that contain searched sequence.

Note: I use elasticsearch v 5.6;

Comment: TEXT should be good enough for this. You can also use information on following links to handle search/filtering:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870172/elasticsearch-for-multiple-language-support, https://greg.blog/2013/05/01/three-principles-for-multilingal-indexing-in-elasticsearch/, https://discuss.elastic.co/t/multiple-language-analyzers-for-one-field/199271

Answer (score 0):

I believe the TEXT type, should be OK. The best possible way is by testing it.

PUT /language_test/sample/1
{
  "sentence" :" 你吃饭了吗？",
  "lang" :"chinese"
}

PUT /language_test/sample/2
{
  "sentence" :"Var kan jag hitta någon som talar engelska?",
  "lang" :"swedish"
}

GET /language_test/_mapping